# Laravel Model $appends or $attribute not Working for Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have User.php and the important part is...

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post', 'post_author', 'ID')
        ->where('post_status', 'publish')->latest('App\Models\Post'::CREATED_AT);
}
```

**Post.php**

```
protected $appends = ['vote_count'];

public function getVoteCountAttribute()
{
    $vote_count = $this->postMeta()
        ->where('meta_key', '=', 'et_vote_count')->first();

    $this->attributes['vote_count'] = !empty($vote_count) ? $vote_count->meta_value : 0;
    // return !empty($vote_count) ? $vote_count : 0;
}
```

I expect the `vote_count` attribute to be loaded when the model is loaded.

**TeacherController.php**

```
$sort_by_vote_count = $teacher->posts->sortByDesc(function ($post, $key) {
    dd($post);
    return $post->vote_count;
});
```

Then I dump the post but I don't see vote_count attribute so I cannot sort by vote_count.

Comment: You can still sort it by the mutator even if it isn't loaded when you retrieve the relationship. `$teacher->posts->sortByDesc('vote_count')`. And your mutator should return the value and not add it to the model attributes.

Comment: Have you tried `get()` on your `$teacher` variable. E.g. `$teacher->posts()->get()...`;

Comment: Also, I noticed you are not add `$query` as a argument in your `getVoteCountAttribute()`. And then not, using `$value`. And also not returning a value. This could be the issue.

Comment: What about the `return !empty($vote_count) ? $vote_count : 0;` line? Have you tried that before?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thx I figured out what was wrong, I needed to return $vote_count->meta_value instead of $vote_count